# Recover mail moved into Outlook's Notes folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

I accidentally put some mail messages in Outlook 2007's "Notes" folder and now I can't get them back.  If you select the Notes folder, all it will show is, unsurprisingly, notes. Can I change this folder to show the messages that I moved here?

I'm connected to an Exchange server, I believe its 2010.  I would have asked our admin, but he's in the middle of moving everyone to Exchange from Lotus Notes (Yay!!!) and is busy as hell, I'm sure.

As background, I accomplished this feat by pressing Ctrl + Shift + V (Move To dialog) and selecting the Notes folder.  If you drag/drop onto the notes folder, it creates a note from the message and leaves the message in its original folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated further and if you use the menus normally, it creates a note when you use the "Move to folder" menu item.  My situation is I have an Autohotkey script that simulates Ctrl + Shift + V then Home then the first letter of the box I needed to move the mail to then presses enter.  (Basically to get my outlook mailbox to have an "Archive" function like GMail does.  I hit the A key and the message disappears from my inbox.)  When the key presses are simulated via AHK, it doesn't create the note.

I'm able to recover these messages by using the "Recover Deleted Items" menu option under tools.  The messages aren't in my Deleted Items folder, though, so I'm not sure what exactly happens to them.

Moral of the story?  BE FREAKING CAREFUL WITH AUTOHOTKEY!